# Testing Foundation modals works in Selenium but not Webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, webkit, capybara

When using :webkit, I can't even test for the presence of my Foundation modal, but everything works fine using :selenium. What gives?

```
it "should open modal" do
  current_path.should eq(root_path)
  page.should have_selector("#modal") # This fails in webkit, works in selenium
end
```

I'm using Capybara 2.4.1 and capybara-webkit 1.3.0.

Comment: Have you found an answer for your question? I'm currently having struggling with the same problem

Comment: I have the same problem...

Comment: experiencing this with foundation-rails (5.5.3.2) and capybara-webkit (1.11.1), too

Answer (score 0):

add this to your test file. a javascript call to open the model is needed since something wrong is hapening and preventing the modal from being opened automaticaly

page.execute_script("
    $('#modal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
  ")

Comment: this does unfortunately not work for me. the popup does not get opened.